# Administration Pages Styling

Tags: theme-development, admin, admin-menu

I am adding administration pages using `add_menu_page()` function. But it wont look good. Check the image below.

[image]

I would like to have it as separated and in between Appearance and Plugins section with rounded borders.

Comment: What image below?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will put one separator right after 'Appearance' and one right before 'Plugins'. Just make sure to give your menu position 62 or 63. You can just add it to whatever file is adding the admin page to begin with. This should be called after everything else has been added.

```
function jpb_menu_isolator(){
  global $menu;
  $menu[61] = array('', 'read', 'separator3', '', 'wp-menu-separator');
  $menu[64] = array('', 'read', 'separator3', '', 'wp-menu-separator');
  uksort($menu,'strnatcasecmp');
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'jpb_menu_isolator', 1000 );
```